# boolean type manipulation

Tags: c++, boolean

this code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  bool t=false;
  cout<<t &&(!t)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

shows me error like this

> invalid operands of types 'bool' and '' to binary
>   'operator<<'

What is wrong? I can't understand this, please explain it to me. I think that `&&` and `!` is defined in c++.

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> "invalid operands of types 'bool' and '' to binary 'operator<<'"

This means that the second `<<` operator is trying to execute on (!t) and 'endl'.

`<<` has a higher precedence than `&&` so your cout statement executes like this:

`(cout << t ) && ( (!t) << endl );`

Add parenthesis to fix this:

`cout << (t  &&  (!t) ) << endl ;`

Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for order of operations when statements are not evaluating as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Add parentheses to get the precedence of operators right:

```
cout << (t && !t) << endl;
```

Equivalently:

```
cout << false << endl;
```

Comment: @user: again, precedence of operators... look it up!

Answer (score 3):

`&&` has lower precedence than `<<`, so the statement is evaluated as `(cout << t) && (!t << endl);`

[C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 2):

You need some more parentheses:

```
cout << (t && !t) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with operator precedence, as **`&&` has lower precedence than `<<`**.

```
cout<<(t && (!t))<<endl;  // ok!
```

Also for any `bool` variable `t` the expression `t && (!t)` always results in `false` and `t || (!t)` always results in `true`. :)